# Is it possible to use regular expressions with fgrep?

Tags: unix, grep

Logically, it would make sense to use the grep command, as that supports regular expressions. My teacher is looking for a solution that would use fgrep to find lines in a file that contain one string, and also a different string. This seems utterly confusing and I'm at a loss as to where to look, as everywhere says to use grep. Is there a way to use fgrep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
fgrep FIRST inputfile.txt | fgrep SECOND
```

That will, as you request, find all lines in `inputfile.txt` containing both `FIRST` and `SECOND` (as your question doesn't seem to care about the order of the strings within the line).